# How do I define this variable from a JSON response?

Tags: json

I am working with calling API data from weather providers and am trying to define a variable mtwnsd24 with the following code:

```
var mtwnsd24 = data.data.coordinates.dates.value[2];

$(".mtwnsd24").append(mtwnsd24);
}
);
```

The response, when run in Postman, gives the following JSON and I want to get the value "42.4".

```
"status": "OK",
   "data": [
    {
        "parameter": "wind_speed_10m:kmh",
        "coordinates": [
            {
                "lat": 40.014994,
                "lon": -73.811646,
                "dates": [
                    {
                        "date": "2020-01-04T05:00:00Z",
                        "value": 5.0
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "2020-01-05T05:00:00Z",
                        "value": 42.4
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "2020-01-06T05:00:00Z",
                        "value": 17.7
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
      },
```

The definition nor any variations seem to work.

Comment: You may want to tag this question with the used programming language. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. That said, the example data you provide is not in JSON format, so you may have additional challenges there.

Comment: According to Meteomatics, the data is JSON.  [link](https://www.meteomatics.com/en/api/response/#json-examples)

Comment: JSON can't end with a comma. Look, nobody should be required to guess what you did and with what data. Please extract and provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

`data.data[0].coordinates[0].dates[1].value`

Result is

`42.4`

Note that json array indexes are zero-based so if you want second element, you need to use index of `1`

Comment: @EricMiller glad to help. If you find my answer helpful you may consider accepting my answer by clicking check mark